# How do I use boost's feature detection and other useful macros? Example: BOOST_OVERRIDE

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on code that needs to compile under older C++ versions (I don't know all the versions applicable). Specifically, I would like to use the macro BOOST_OVERRIDE. There are several others.

How do I reliably access these macros? I can boost/config/detail/suffix.hpp but that doesn't seem to be the right approach (delving into boost internals).

We use boost 1.78

Comment: Feature detection macro is named `BOOST_NO_CXX11_OVERRIDE` ... `BOOST_OVERRIDE` only expands to `override` or to nothing depending on it. As need for code compilable with pre-C++11 compilers is getting rather rare it is usually better to just use  `override` keyword instead of `BOOST_OVERRIDE`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib did you mean "[not] use `override`"?

Comment: No I meant to use override. The keyword helps to read the code and to discover defects caused by typos or partial maintenance. It is unlikely to need to use old compiler that does not support that keyword. Such compilers also lack several performance improvements (like constexpr and move semantics) so should be considered to be upgraded away from if only possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All feature detection macros defined by [Boost.Config](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) become available by including `boost/config.hpp`. You should not need to include any other headers for feature detection, and certainly, you should never include anything from the `detail` subdirectory.

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>

struct interface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct impl :
    public interface
{
    void foo() BOOST_OVERRIDE
    {
    }
};
```

Boost.Config also defines a few other utilities that are defined in separate headers. For example, `boost/config/auto_link.hpp` allows enabling automatic linting to libraries on compilers that support this feature, and `boost/config/workaround.hpp` defines a few macros for testing compiler versions to apply workarounds. But for the purpose of feature detection, `boost/config.hpp` should be the only include you need.